# Inconsistent behaviour from appengine aetest

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, go

I'm trying to test a function that should fetch all the objects of a certain kind from the datastore.

Within the test it appears I have to insert a sleep to make the query find all the saved items.

The code below is a reproducible example. The first log trace is from when the sleep line is commented out, and the second when the sleep is uncommented. Note the length: 0 and length: 3

I'm assuming this is an eventual consistency issue, which would arise in production if I persisted several objects and immediately queried for them. But in production, these items were persisted long beforehand. Since this situation only arises for my test, is there something I'm meant to be doing to force the datastore to wait till it has fully saved the items before continuing?

I tried wrapping the test saves in a transaction, but got an "Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions" error.

```
type Thing struct {
  Str1 string
  Str2 string
}

func (thing Thing) Save(c appengine.Context) error {
  k := datastore.NewKey(c, "Thing", thing.Str1 + "_" + thing.Str2, 0, nil)
  if _, err := datastore.Put(c, k, &thing); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}

func GetThings(c appengine.Context) ([]Thing, error) {
  var things []Thing
  q := datastore.NewQuery("Thing").
      Filter("Str1=", "thing")
  _, err := q.GetAll(c, &things)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return things, nil
}



func TestGetThings(t *testing.T) {
  c, _ := aetest.NewContext(nil)
  defer c.Close()
  thing1 := Thing{"thing", "1"}
  thing2 := Thing{"thing", "2"}
  thing3 := Thing{"thing", "3"}
  thing1.Save(c)
  thing2.Save(c)
  thing3.Save(c)

//  time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)

  things, err := GetThings(c)
  if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
  }
  t.Log("length:" + strconv.Itoa(len(things)))
}
```

**Logs when sleep commented out**

C:\Users\XXXX>goapp test thing -test.v

2014/09/23 21:24:05 appengine: not running under devappserver2; using some default configuration

=== RUN TestGetThings

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:07,328 devappserver2.py:725] Skipping SDK update check.

WARNING  2014-09-23 21:24:07,328 devappserver2.py:741] DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME will not be set correctly with --port=0

WARNING  2014-09-23 21:24:07,351 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:07,365 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: `http://localhost:50153`

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:07,371 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "default" running at: `http://localhost:50154`

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:07,377 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: `http://localhost:50155`

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:08,378 api_server.py:583] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:08,388 api_server.py:586] Saving search indexes
--- PASS: TestGetThings (4.60 seconds)

thing_test.go:87: length:0

PASS

ok      thing    4.729s

**Logs when sleep not commented out**

C:\Users\XXXX>goapp test thing -test.v

2014/09/23 21:24:28 appengine: not running under devappserver2; using some default configuration

=== RUN TestGetThings

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:31,124 devappserver2.py:725] Skipping SDK update check.

WARNING  2014-09-23 21:24:31,124 devappserver2.py:741] DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME will not be set correctly with --port=0

WARNING  2014-09-23 21:24:31,148 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:31,164 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: `http://localhost:50191`

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:31,171 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "default" running at: `http://localhost:50192`

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:31,176 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: `http://localhost:50193`

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:34,176 api_server.py:583] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore

INFO     2014-09-23 21:24:34,176 api_server.py:586] Saving search indexes
--- PASS: TestGetThings (6.83 seconds)

thing_test.go:87: length:3

PASS

ok      thing    6.987s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, the solution is to use the Options parameter when creating the aetest.NewContext.

```
c, _ := aetest.NewContext(&aetest.Options{"", true})
```

The second item in the Options struct is a boolean named StronglyConsistentDatastore.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into [Eventual Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) situation. You can read on that in the prev link or in the [GoLang Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/). You need to make a choice, is getting the data sooner worth having slower writes. If you need your data right after you put it you need to do [Ancestor Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Ancestor_queries) which will slow down writes but will make your data available immediately after. There are other constraints with Ancestors (like transactions) but for your immediate concern it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't answer my question, which on reflection may be unclear. My problem is setting up the test case. I want the three Things to be stored properly in the datastore before I call GetThings(). In production the Things would have been saved a long time beforehand.